# Measure between two images in QGIS 3.18

Tags: qgis, pixel, measurements

I'm currently working on QGIS 3.18 in the area of geo-referencing. I have two orthophotos (they are same) but the first one is untreated, the second was corrected by differential GPS. I want to measure the difference in geo-referencing between these images and particularly the shift.

My idea is to identify noticeable pixel in these images and measure the shift between these pixels, but I have no idea how to make that. How can I do this?

Answer (score 1):

[image]

Not a very elegant solution but you could try using the measure line tool (the tool with a ruler or ctrl + shift + m) and perhaps toggle between images to get the offset distance.

Comment: Thanks you for your reply.
The result is not really accurate by it works.
If you ever have another idea for, for example analyzing the shift between several pairs of points, I'm very interested.

Comment: Ok so Im still somewhat new to qgis stuff but this is what I've found out so far, if you go to vector > analysis tools > Distance matrix. It looks like this tool can compute the distance between two different vector layers. In your case it would be the untreated vs the GPS corrected points. You could select nearest neighbor = 1 to find the closest point and compute that difference. The resulting output is a distance matrix layer, which means you can open up the Attribute Table and see the distance between points.

Comment: This might help : https://www.displayr.com/what-is-a-distance-matrix/

Comment: hope this helps

Comment: Thanks you for your reply, I will try it.